# Хочу создать несколько вариантов ответов

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Что нужно добавить, чтобы при вводе не только 16, но и 17,18, и других значений выводилось 'Отлично!'

```
name = input('Сколько тебе лет? : ')
n = 'Не правильно!' if name != ("16") else 'Отлично!'
print (n)
name2 = input('В каком городе ты живешь? : ')
No = 'Врёшь!' if name2 != "Питер" else 'Круто!'
print (No)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, перечислить в коллекции (`tuple`, `list`, `set`, и т.п.) и через `in` проверить:

```
n = 'Не правильно!' if name not in ("16", "17", "18") else 'Отлично!'

# OR:

n = 'Отлично!' if name in ("16", "17", "18") else 'Не правильно!'
```

Либо стареньким способом через `if`:

```
if name == "16" or name == "17" or name == "18":
    n = 'Отлично!'
else:
    n = 'Не правильно!'

# OR:

n = 'Отлично!' if name == "16" or name == "17" or name == "18" else 'Не правильно!'
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень помогли)

Comment: @Stranger, тогда примите ответ как верный, чтобы не висел этот вопрос без ответа )